# How does laravel's mod rewrite rule work?

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite

The rewrite rule in laravel's .htaccess file is

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php
```

Now when I visit a url say site/public/home the request url according to server variable is site/public/home.
My question is , based on what I understand this rule rewrites beginning of the url, so it must be like index.phpsite/public/home.

What part of url is being replaced by "index.php" and how does it appear in server variable as if nothing happened to it? 
Also does this mean that url rewrites from htacces file doesn't affect the url stored in server variable?

Comment: **^** in  rewrite pattern matches the full request URI and rewrites it to **/index.php** ,in short if u enter domain.com/file , your browser will stay on /file but you will see content of /index.php

Comment: So does that mean that url rewrites won't affect server variables like REQUEST_URI? Because on echoing that variable I still get original/request/path

Comment: Yes, I always found the name "rewrite" quite misleading. It is like "Hey, Laravel, I want your index.php as always, but you also get the URL the user wanted, so play with it"